# Is it possible to make an Objective-C project (no UI, no simulator) to be tested on Travis (travis-ci.org)?

Tags: objective-c, travis-ci

I wonder if it is possible to make an Objective-C project (no UI, no simulator is needed, hosted on Github) to be built on Travis?

Current [Travis docs](http://about.travis-ci.org/) seems not to contain any information regarding the option to have Objective-C projects built on Travis.

But [Building a C Project](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/c/) says that:

```
Travis VMs are 32 bit and currently provide

gcc 4.6
clang 3.1
core GNU build toolchain (autotools, make), cmake, scons
```

and that default test script is run like

```
./configure && make && make test
```

So, to rephrase the subject question:

Do any workarounds exist to make SenTestingKit test suite, that my project currently uses, behave like a C test suite, so it could be treated as such by Travis VM?

NOTE 1: Here is the list of resources, which seem to be related to the question:

[Compiling Objective-C without a GUI](http://codeseekah.com/2012/09/12/compiling-objective-c-without-a-gui/). It claims that `Both gcc and clang compile Objective-C 2.0` and that sounds very promising!

**NOTE 2: I suspect that it is possible to use some testing tool other than SenTestingKit:
this tool should be easy to be run without a GUI and without `xcodebuild` etc: I've opened related issue for that: [Is there any non-Xcode-based command line testing tool for Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714356/is-there-any-non-xcode-based-command-line-testing-tool-for-objective-c?lq=1). I am even thinking about writing an easy one just to be used by my project.**

Comment: MacOS or iOS application? That will make a big difference, since iOS applications need a simulator to be running.

Comment: I built it for iOS app, but it is not related to any UI, GUI... Currently I run my SenTestingKit suite using default "Xcode + SenTest test target" setup and so simulator opens, but only to run SenTests. The code itself does not do any UI operations!

Comment: Check this: https://somethingaboutios.wordpress.com/2016/02/05/add-travis-ci-to-your-coding-challenge/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few days [Travis announced](http://about.travis-ci.org/blog/introducing-mac-ios-rubymotion-testing/) that they are now also supporting objetive-c projects. See [Building An Objective-C Project](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/objective-c/) for more info.

**Update**

It is even possible to make Travis launch the simulator so that you can run application tests and UI related stuff. I required a little extra work, but it's pretty straight forward. [I wrote about it here](http://kaspermunck.github.io/2013/04/running-kiwi-specs-with-travis-ci/).